# Firebase Мультизапросы

Tags: android, firebase

Я использую Cloud Firestore и мне надо каким-то образом делать мультизапросы

Это можно сравнить с системой подписок

Код того что использую ниже

```
private CollectionReference ref;
ref = firebaseFirestore.collection("Data");
```

После объявления идет интересная вещь: я захожу в коллекцию где лежат юзеры и сгружаю данные по имени

```
for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                ref.whereEqualTo("name", doc.getDocument().getId());
            }
```

И тут возникает проблема, потому что, насколько я понимаю, он сначала ищет схождение на первое имя, а потом по тем файлам, которые он выделил ищет другое имя, но так как их там нет, ибо отобрали по другому имени, он сгружает все(без корявой картинки в Paint пост - не пост)

Объяснение картинки:

Допустим у меня БД и в ней три цвет: черный, красный, зеленый

Мне нужны красный и зеленый

```
ArrayList<String> color = new ArrayList<>();
color.add("green");
color.add("red");
```

Я пишу в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < color.size(); i++) {

        ref.whereEqualTo("color", color.get(i));

    }
```

Что делает бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я хочу чтобы она делала ? Хочу чтобы сначала загрузила все фильтры а потом пошла искать по БД

Например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перерыл половину сайтом по Firebase - ничего, на Стаке пусто, в чатах никто не знает, на роликах с аналогами они тупо делают такую дичь

```
for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            ref.whereEqualTo("name", doc.getDocument().getId());
            ref.collection()...
        }
```

А то не самая лучшая идея ибо нельзя отсортировать по дате и он будет сгружать всю базу: лимит не поставить ибо будет лимит - будут всего понемногу сгружать, но например пост от 2015 может быть выше поста с вчерашнего дня